# PHP create xml Extra content at the end of the document error

Tags: php, xml

```
<?php 
// Display the error message according to each data code.
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><results>'; 
if($_GET['code'] == "500"){
    $xml .= '<error id="500" message="Error 500"></error>';     
}else if($_GET['code'] == "501"){
    $xml .= '<error id="501" message="Error 501"></error>'; 
}
$xml .= '</results>';
header ("Content-Type:text/xml"); 
echo ($xml);  
?>
```

I got this error

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

In plaintext form

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><results><error id="501" message="Invalid Course Code"></error>   </results>  
   <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
   <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Comment: Have you tried putting a new line befor the results opening tag?

Comment: What do you mean by new line before results?

Comment: Is there no extra whitespace after the `?>` PHP closing tag?

Comment: Could you show the rest of the browser error report?

Comment: Or better, the complete XML result.

Comment: No more data shown. All copied.

Comment: How to see the complete XML result? I want it look like <results><error id="500" message="Error 500"></error></results>

Comment: Replace the `header()` call with `header("content-type: text/plain");` to get a plain result and post that result.

Comment: That XML renders fine in my browser (Firefox 19 on Linux). What browser do you use?

Comment: Wow... something you don't see: there is HTML comments and **a script tag** in your output. Remove that.

Comment: It is not putting by me, I host it to a hosting server and getting this error, it work in wamp server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works on your WAMPP server, because it is not outputting the analytics code your hoster seems to add:

```
   <!-- Hosting24 Analytics Code -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://stats.hosting24.com/count.php"></script>
   <!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

Contact your hoster on how to remove that from your output (or better, switch hosts, because this is kind of outrageous).